error in code that i gave to train yolov7 model
this is my google colab link- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zoBsPKvrBKSUciQ9SLRvdO1lrutxg8eJ?usp=sharing
the code--
%cd /content/yolov7
!python train.py --batch 16 --epochs 55 --data {dataset.location}/data.yaml --weights 'yolov7_training.pt' --device 0
this is the error i am getting--
2024-05-23 09:15:09.028892: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-05-23 09:15:09.028943: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-05-23 09:15:09.030271: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-05-23 09:15:09.037652: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-05-23 09:15:10.100115: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
YOLOR  b2a7de9 torch 2.3.0+cu121 CUDA:0 (Tesla T4, 15102.0625MB)
Namespace(weights='yolov7_training.pt', cfg='', data='/content/Bike_repo-1/data.yaml', hyp='data/hyp.scratch.p5.yaml', epochs=55, batch_size=16, img_size=[640, 640], rect=False, resume=False, nosave=False, notest=False, noautoanchor=False, evolve=False, bucket='', cache_images=False, image_weights=False, device='0', multi_scale=False, single_cls=False, adam=False, sync_bn=False, local_rank=-1, workers=8, project='runs/train', entity=None, name='exp', exist_ok=False, quad=False, linear_lr=False, label_smoothing=0.0, upload_dataset=False, bbox_interval=-1, save_period=-1, artifact_alias='latest', freeze=[0], v5_metric=False, world_size=1, global_rank=-1, save_dir='runs/train/exp7', total_batch_size=16)
tensorboard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs/train', view at http://localhost:6006/
hyperparameters: lr0=0.01, lrf=0.1, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=0.05, cls=0.3, cls_pw=1.0, obj=0.7, obj_pw=1.0, iou_t=0.2, anchor_t=4.0, fl_gamma=0.0, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.2, scale=0.9, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.15, copy_paste=0.0, paste_in=0.15, loss_ota=1
wandb: Install Weights & Biases for YOLOR logging with 'pip install wandb' (recommended)
Overriding model.yaml nc=80 with nc=6
             from  n    params  module                                  arguments                     

0                -1  1       928  models.common.Conv                      [3, 32, 3, 1]
1                -1  1     18560  models.common.Conv                      [32, 64, 3, 2]
2                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]
3                -1  1     73984  models.common.Conv                      [64, 128, 3, 2]
4                -1  1      8320  models.common.Conv                      [128, 64, 1, 1]
5                -2  1      8320  models.common.Conv                      [128, 64, 1, 1]
6                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]
7                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]
8                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]
9                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]
10  [-1, -3, -5, -6]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
11                -1  1     66048  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 1, 1]
12                -1  1         0  models.common.MP                        []
13                -1  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1]
14                -3  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1]
15                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 2]
16          [-1, -3]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
17                -1  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1]
18                -2  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1]
19                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1]
20                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1]
21                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1]
22                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1]
23  [-1, -3, -5, -6]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
24                -1  1    263168  models.common.Conv                      [512, 512, 1, 1]
25                -1  1         0  models.common.MP                        []
26                -1  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1]
27                -3  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1]
28                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 2]
29          [-1, -3]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
30                -1  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1]
31                -2  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1]
32                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1]
33                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1]
34                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1]
35                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1]
36  [-1, -3, -5, -6]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
37                -1  1   1050624  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 1024, 1, 1]
38                -1  1         0  models.common.MP                        []
39                -1  1    525312  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 512, 1, 1]
40                -3  1    525312  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 512, 1, 1]
41                -1  1   2360320  models.common.Conv                      [512, 512, 3, 2]
42          [-1, -3]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
43                -1  1    262656  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 256, 1, 1]
44                -2  1    262656  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 256, 1, 1]
45                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1]
46                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1]
47                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1]
48                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1]
49  [-1, -3, -5, -6]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
50                -1  1   1050624  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 1024, 1, 1]
51                -1  1   7609344  models.common.SPPCSPC                   [1024, 512, 1]
52                -1  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1]
53                -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample    [None, 2, 'nearest']
54                37  1    262656  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 256, 1, 1]
55          [-1, -2]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
56                -1  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1]
57                -2  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1]
58                -1  1    295168  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 3, 1]
59                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1]
60                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1]
61                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1]
62[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
63                -1  1    262656  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 256, 1, 1]
64                -1  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1]
65                -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample    [None, 2, 'nearest']
66                24  1     65792  models.common.Conv                      [512, 128, 1, 1]
67          [-1, -2]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
68                -1  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1]
69                -2  1     33024  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 1, 1]
70                -1  1     73856  models.common.Conv                      [128, 64, 3, 1]
71                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]
72                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]
73                -1  1     36992  models.common.Conv                      [64, 64, 3, 1]
74[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
75                -1  1     65792  models.common.Conv                      [512, 128, 1, 1]
76                -1  1         0  models.common.MP                        []
77                -1  1     16640  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 1, 1]
78                -3  1     16640  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 1, 1]
79                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 2]
80      [-1, -3, 63]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
81                -1  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1]
82                -2  1    131584  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 1, 1]
83                -1  1    295168  models.common.Conv                      [256, 128, 3, 1]
84                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1]
85                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1]
86                -1  1    147712  models.common.Conv                      [128, 128, 3, 1]
87[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
88                -1  1    262656  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 256, 1, 1]
89                -1  1         0  models.common.MP                        []
90                -1  1     66048  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 1, 1]
91                -3  1     66048  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 1, 1]
92                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 2]
93      [-1, -3, 51]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
94                -1  1    525312  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 512, 1, 1]
95                -2  1    525312  models.common.Conv                      [1024, 512, 1, 1]
96                -1  1   1180160  models.common.Conv                      [512, 256, 3, 1]
97                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1]
98                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1]
99                -1  1    590336  models.common.Conv                      [256, 256, 3, 1]
100[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]  1         0  models.common.Concat                    [1]
101                -1  1   1049600  models.common.Conv                      [2048, 512, 1, 1]
102                75  1    328704  models.common.RepConv                   [128, 256, 3, 1]
103                88  1   1312768  models.common.RepConv                   [256, 512, 3, 1]
104               101  1   5246976  models.common.RepConv                   [512, 1024, 3, 1]
105   [102, 103, 104]  1     61126  models.yolo.IDetect                     [6, [[12, 16, 19, 36, 40, 28], [36, 75, 76, 55, 72, 146], [142, 110, 192, 243, 459, 401]], [256, 512, 1024]]
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/functional.py:512: UserWarning: torch.meshgrid: in an upcoming release, it will be required to pass the indexing argument. (Triggered internally at ../aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp:3587.)
return _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
Model Summary: 415 layers, 37223526 parameters, 37223526 gradients, 105.2 GFLOPS
Transferred 557/566 items from yolov7_training.pt
WARNING: Dataset not found, nonexistent paths: ['/content/yolov7/Bike_repo-1/valid/images']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/content/yolov7/train.py", line 616, in 
train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer)
File "/content/yolov7/train.py", line 97, in train
check_dataset(data_dict)  # check
File "/content/yolov7/utils/general.py", line 173, in check_dataset
raise Exception('Dataset not found.')
Exception: Dataset not found.   how to solve this error
